# Converting object to Dictionary<PropertyName, Value>

Tags: c#

I have a use case, where I have to show any List of objects `List<T> objects` as a table. So, I have implemented a function, which prepares the data in usable format:

```
public static Dictionary<Guid, Dictionary<string, object>> PrepareList<T>(List<T> Items, List<string> RelevantProperties)
        {
            var res = new Dictionary<Guid, Dictionary<string, object>>();
            var propDicSplitted = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

            foreach (string relevantProperty in RelevantProperties)
            {
                if (relevantProperty.Contains("."))
                {
                    var split = relevantProperty.Split('.');
                    if(!propDicSplitted.ContainsKey(split[0]))
                    {
                        propDicSplitted.Add(split[0], new List<string>());
                    }
                    propDicSplitted[split[0]].Add(relevantProperty);
                }
            }

            foreach (T item in Items)
            {
                var itemPropDic = item.ToDictionary();

                var itemId = (Guid)itemPropDic["ID"];
                if (!res.ContainsKey(itemId))
                {
                    res.Add(itemId, new Dictionary<string, object>());
                }

                foreach(string relevantProperty in RelevantProperties)
                {
                    if (itemPropDic.ContainsKey(relevantProperty)) { 
                        res[itemId].Add(relevantProperty, itemPropDic[relevantProperty]);
                    }
                }

                foreach(string subObjectName in propDicSplitted.Keys)
                {
                    foreach (string relevantSubProperty in propDicSplitted[subObjectName])
                    {
                        res[itemId].Add(relevantSubProperty, GetNestedPropertyValue(itemPropDic, relevantSubProperty.Split('.')));
                    }
                }

            }
            return res;
        }

        private static object GetNestedPropertyValue(IDictionary<string, object> Obj, string[] PropertiesPath)
        {
            if (PropertiesPath.Length == 1)
                return Obj[PropertiesPath[0]];

            return GetNestedPropertyValue(Obj[PropertiesPath[0]].ToDictionary(), PropertiesPath.Skip(1).ToArray());
        }
```

where, `List<T> items` is the list of items to be shown in table and `List<string> RelevantProperties` are the property names, which are relevant for the table. These can be nested via '.' (eg. when the `Orders` object has a `Customer` object as a property and I need to show the customer name, then it will be possible to add value to `RelevantProperties` as "Customer.Name", which then will be extracted).

The `.ToDictionary()` method is extended to provide the access to the properties as in dictionary:

```
public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this object source, bool ignoreComplexTypes = false)
        {
            return source.ToDictionary<object>(ignoreComplexTypes);
        }

        public static IDictionary<string, T> ToDictionary<T>(this object source, bool ignoreComplexTypes)
        {
            if (source == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("source", "Unable to convert object to a dictionary. The source object is null.");

            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, T>();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(source))
                AddPropertyToDictionary<T>(property, source, dictionary, ignoreComplexTypes);
            return dictionary;
        }

        private static void AddPropertyToDictionary<T>(PropertyDescriptor property, object source, Dictionary<string, T> dictionary, bool ignoreComplexTypes)
        {
            object value = property.GetValue(source);
            if (IsOfType<T>(value) && !(ignoreComplexTypes))
                dictionary.Add(property.Name, (T)value);
        }

        private static bool IsOfType<T>(object value)
        {
            return value is T;
        }
```

However, the problem is that the function `PrepareList<T>()` is too slow and it takes 2 minutes for a list with 10000 items and 8 relevant properties. I need a hint on how to optimize this. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: question: are you *actually showing* 10,000 rows in the table? most tables aren't useful beyond 50 or so rows; and if you are paging it: only run the map step for the rows you're *actually displaying*? or - don't even run the map step: most UI tools for building a table, *don't ever do this* - they just get the descriptor data and execute it directly per cell, without building something like a dictionary in the middle

Comment: Have you tried to locate the bottleneck using a `Stopwatch`? Will the relevant properties change per item? Otherwise you could just get the relevant properties one time. I tested the code with 100.000 items and 10 relevant properties(not nested) and it took 781ms to complete.

Comment: @MarcGravell, so you say that if I just pass to the Datatables (for ex) a list of objects and relevant column names, it should be sufficient , without preparing the data in the right format?

Comment: that's impossible to comment on here; there is no "right format" if you're just shuffling things around - or, equally: all formats are "right". If performance is your concern, "do the least stuff" is a great aim, so if you don't *need* 10,000 dictionaries: don't create them?

Comment: @RedFox, did previously for some 2000 items and was ok, but not for too many with many nested properties. I guess the problem might indeed be with the nested properties in function GetNestedPropertyValue()